# EventTrigger bind to event from DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="{Binding MyEvent}">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAnimation}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

MyEvent is event from my DataContext.

This does not work because RoutedEvent can't be Binding expression. Any idea how to accomplish this? 
In fact, I need some mix of EventTrigger and DataTrigger...

Solution with Blend SDK:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Interactivity:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding}" EventName="MyEvent">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play">
            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    ....
                </Storyboard>
            </ei:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
        </ei:ControlStoryboardAction>
    </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: why trigger at all? can you not create a command, which starts your storyboard, and call that command's execute from wherever you want?

Comment: Just for clarifying.. Do you want to add custom events that you'll be able to raise manually?

Comment: Yes, I have event in my ViewModel, which I raise manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the EventTriggers from `Interactivity` ([Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801)) can trigger on any event on any object, the native ones only work for `RoutedEvents` which you normally only have on controls.

Comment: ok, but how to set it to bind to event from DataContext? I've been trying a lot and can't make it work...

Comment: @pedala: Set the `SourceObject` to `{Binding}`, the `EventName` to the name of the event.

Comment: I've been trying that and it didnt work. Now i tried it directly on control and it worked. Probably there's problem because it's inside `DataTemplate`? Where exactly should I put `Interactivity` inside this `DataTemplate`? I've put it inside `Grid` element because I can't put it in the root of `DataTemplate` as I've put `Trigger` in the question..

Comment: @pedala: Use the root element of the `DataTemplate` as it needs an object to attach to.

Comment: I was using `SourceName` instead of `SourceObject`. This part is working now. But, when I raise this event, I get exception: `No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'MyGrid'.` Any idea what that might be?

Comment: I solved this exception. I've put `Storyboard` inside `ControlStoryboardAction` instead of using it as a StaticResource. Thank you very much!